# What Number of objects must be equal to?

Tags: modbus

Modbus function `2B` "Encapsulated Interface Transport" has encapsulated MEI type `0E` "Read Device Identification". Server responce for this request has "Number Of Objects" field that is described as "Number of identification Object returned in the response (for an individual access, Number Of Objects = 1)".

If the response packet has no enough space to place all identification objects, transaction may be splitted to separate packets. In this case the field "More Follows" must be equal to `FF`, the field "Next Object Id" must be equal to number of first object that weren't placed into this packet. But what the field "Number of objects" must be equal to?

Modbus Application Protocol Specification has an example:

First transaction:

| Request |  | Response |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *Field Name* | *Value* | *Field Name* | *Value* |
| Function | 2B | Function | 2B |
| MEI Type | 0E | MEI type | 0E |
| Read Dev Id Code | 01 | Read Dev Id Code | 01 |
| Object Id | 00 | Conformity Level | 01 |
|  |  | More Follows | FF |
|  |  | Next Object Id | 02 |
|  |  | Number Of Objects | 03 |
|  |  | Object Id | 00 |
|  |  | Object Length | 16 |
|  |  | Object Value | "Company identification" |
|  |  | Object Id | 01 |
|  |  | Object Length | 1C |
|  |  | Object Value | "Product code XXXXXX" |

Second transaction:

| Request |  | Response |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *Field Name* | *Value* | *Field Name* | *Value* |
| Function | 2B | Function | 2B |
| MEI Type | 0E | MEI type | 0E |
| Read Dev Id Code | 01 | Read Dev Id Code | 01 |
| Object Id | 02 | Conformity Level | 01 |
|  |  | More Follows | 00 |
|  |  | Next Object Id | 00 |
|  |  | Number Of Objects | 03 |
|  |  | Object Id | 02 |
|  |  | Object Length | 05 |
|  |  | Object Value | "V2.11" |

In this example both responses have `"Number of object" = 3`, so this field must be equal to entire number of objects for selected `Read Dev Id Code`. There the very bad Modbus feature goes to scene: Modbus ADU doesn't contains full packet length. When identification packet has `"Number of objects" = 3`, calculating of actual packet size is impossible. **Specification doesn't contains any explanation of what `Number of objects` must be equal when `MoreFollows==FF`**. Is it error in Modbus Application Protocol Specification?

I examined several Modbus libraries for this subject. Most libraries have not implemented Modbus Encapsulated Interface, so I found only two convient libraries.

## pymodbus

https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/dev/pymodbus/mei_message.py

### Constructing responce:

*Line 181*

When this lib constructs device identification response it places number of objects that is actually presented in packet.

### Parsing response:

*Line 194*

When this lib parses device identification response it reads number of object from corresponding packet field, after that reads each object **until packet ended**.

## Qt

https://github.com/qt/qtserialbus/blob/dev/src/serialbus/qmodbusdeviceidentification.cpp

### Parsing response:

*Line 213*

When this lib parses device identification response it reads number of objects from corresponding packet field, after that reads `Number Of Object` objects.

Qt has no identification response constructor.

So, we have at least two libraries that implements identification response putting actually presented number of objects.

Your opinions, what `Number of objects` must be equal to when `More Follows == FF`?

The document I referenced:
https://modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b.pdf

Comment: Did you find the info? I have similar issue trying to design parser for the id packet data, in particular identifying the would-be size of the packet basing on incomplete packet data available. My conclusion is it is not possible to properly parse partial data of id chain without having all the previous history ("more follows" packets). Number of object seems to list total count of data fields **supported**, which can be returned for this type of query in consecutive querying. No info if the field ids must be consecutive.

Comment: But I may be totally wrong. The manual states "number of objects = Number of identification Object returned in the response (for an individual access, Number Of Objects = 1)", this means for first packet it must be equal to 2, for second equal to 1. Then things get properly aligned - you know the number of chunks in each packet, and you know if it is complete (mode follows=0) or you need to ask for more (more follows=ff) with specific property id (object id)

Comment: @Anonymous, I think this is an error in example. In my application I put in this field number of objects that is *actually present in current packet*.